# A JavaScript error occurred in the main process : Electron

Tags: angular, electron, electron-packager

I am trying to package an electron app using electron packager. After successfully packaging the app, when I open the app file, it throws the following error.

[image: Javascript error occured in the main process]

Version that am using,

npm - 5.4.1
node - 6.11.0
electron - 1.6.11

Please help if anyone has already resolved this.